# Css is set in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
function MyFitText2(width, height, span) {
    var fontSize = 20;
    $(span).css('font-size', fontSize);
    do {
        fontSize = fontSize - 1;
        textHeight = $(span).height();
        textWidth = $(span).width();
        $(span).css('font-size', fontSize);
    } while ((textHeight > height || textWidth > width) && fontSize > 1);
}
```

and use:

```
var pinkboxspan = "<span style=\"position:absolute; left:" + $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxLeft"] + "px; top:" + $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxBoxTop"] + "px; " +
                        "text-align:left; font-weight: bold; color: red; background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 215, 15, 0.5),rgba(255, 215, 15, 0.5));" +
                        "line-height:1.1; " +
                        "\">" + text + "</span>&nbsp;";

MyFitText2($thisPinkBox["PinkBoxWidth"], $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxHeight"], pinkboxspan);
$(pinkboxspan).css('width', $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxWidth"] + 'px');
$(pinkboxspan).css('height', $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxHeight"] + 'px');
```

but in result:

```
<span style="position:absolute; left:870px; top:413px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; color: red; background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 215, 15, 0.5),rgba(255, 215, 15, 0.5));line-height:1.1; ">Sergey's Office
<br>Y Amphitheatre Parkway
<br>Mountain View, CA XXXXX
<br>United States
<br></span>
```

then I add it to DOM by the following way:

```
var imageElement = $("<div style='text-align:left;'><div style='position: relative; display: inline-block;'><img style='position: relative; vertical-align: central;' src='" + $('#previewImage').attr('src') + "' /></div></div>");

var divElement = imageElement.find('div');

var divContent = '';
     // code above in $.each
     divContent = divContent + pinkboxspan;

divElement.append(divContent);

$('#divOverlay').html(divElement);
```

so, parameters width/height are not set. Why and how to solve it?

Comment: Where and how you are appending `pinkboxspan`  to DOM?

Comment: @Satpal, yes, you asked how I add it to DOM, I show code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating jQuery object which is not persisted and manipulating its CSS rules, thus modified CSS properties are not reflected.

Create a jQuery object and use it through out code.

```
var span = $(pinkboxspan);
span = MyFitText2($thisPinkBox["PinkBoxWidth"], $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxHeight"], span);
span.css('width', $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxWidth"] + 'px');

//if you need string
pinkboxspan = span.prop('outerHTML');

function MyFitText2(width, height, span) {
    span.css('font-size', 20);
    //Manipulate Span properties
    return span;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the jquery object in the begining so change your pinkboxspan assignment to...

```
var pinkboxspan = $("<span style=\"position:absolute; left:" + $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxLeft"] + "px; top:" + $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxBoxTop"] + "px; " +
                    "text-align:left; font-weight: bold; color: red; background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 215, 15, 0.5),rgba(255, 215, 15, 0.5));" +
                    "line-height:1.1; " +
                    "\">" + text + "</span>&nbsp;");
```

then make changes to the other code to use pinkboxspan as a jquery object and not plain text...

```
MyFitText2($thisPinkBox["PinkBoxWidth"], $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxHeight"], pinkboxspan);
pinkboxspan.css('width', $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxWidth"] + 'px');
pinkboxspan.css('height', $thisPinkBox["PinkBoxHeight"] + 'px');
```

make changes to your function as well...

```
function MyFitText2(width, height, span) {
    var fontSize = 20;
    span.css('font-size', fontSize);
    do {
        fontSize = fontSize - 1;
        textHeight = span.height();
        textWidth = span.width();
        span.css('font-size', fontSize);
    } while ((textHeight > height || textWidth > width) && fontSize > 1);
}
```

And you're done :)

Comment: how can I add it to my DOM then?

Comment: Select the element you want to add it to using the appropraite JQuery selector and use the append method, eg. $("body").append(pinkboxspan)